# How to join two tables in foxpro9 without common fields

Tags: sql, join, foxpro

I  have two tables in foxpro9.
Table1

```
nParaID    cParaYear   cParaCD     cParaNo    

138        2016        VTMC          1
134        2016        SFCC          1
130        2016        GMLC          1
```

Table2

```
cFtyCD    cInvNo    cCm_Sgl_TaxInv
VTM       001/20
SFC       008/20
GML       65/S
```

When we join this two it should be

```
cFtyCD=cParaCD.
```

How can I join this two?

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the shorter code appears to be a 3-character, you can join based on the LEFT 3 characters in the other table.

```
select;
      t1.nParaID,;
      t1.cParaYear,;
      t1.cParaCd,;
      t1.cParaNo,;
      t2.cFytCD,;
      t2.cInvNo,;
      t2.cCm_Sgl_TaxInv;
   from;
      Tbl1 t1;
         JOIN Tbl2 t2;
            on LEFT( t1.cParaCD, 3)  = t2.cFtyCD
```